# Billings API - runAs user doesn't work as expected

Tags: apex, unit-test, cpq, cpq-api

I'm doing a test class on a batch that trigger some call to the **Salesforce billings API**.

Even if I give the good right on the running as user, I have this issue on the field `blng__CreditNoteLine__c.Debit__c`
[image]

The test class:

```
@isTest
    static void testCaseWhereCNShouldNotBeUpdated() {
        User uCpq = [SELECT id FROM User WHERE alias = 'test123'];
        // add permset to allow cn with type Negative line conversion           
        TestUtils.setPermissionSetListToUser(uCpq, new List<String>{ 'CPQAdmin', BlngAdmin });
        System.runAs(uCpq) {
            Test.startTest();
            CNConvertedSetFieldBatch b = new CNConvertedSetFieldBatch();
            Database.executebatch(b, 50);
            Test.stopTest();               
        }
    }
```

After some investigation, I found out that if I give the permission on the user who launch the test Class, I dont have the error anymore.

Is there any clean implementation to force the blng API to check the runningAs user right and not the right of the user who start the test ?

EDIT: I tried [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310820/testmethod-permissionset-assignment-has-no-effect-on-fls-checks) solution but in the case of biling API it doesn't work. I think that the way that the api check right is a specific process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testmethod PermissionSet Assignment has no effect on FLS checks](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310820/testmethod-permissionset-assignment-has-no-effect-on-fls-checks)

Comment: This solution look nice but unfortunately it doesn't work in my case. It might be missing something in the case of Billings API

Comment: the user that launches the test class - almost certainly is a System Admin so it is not clear if that accomplishes your unit test goal

Comment: @cropredy yes this is a basic admin from a scratch org. 
We didn't added blng permission to this user.